# Overvoltage protection for RS485 from DC-DC voltage

Tags: dc, 12v, rs485, tvs

I am making a circuit to protect RS485 against 24V and 32V DC over-voltage. Note that my power supply is 12V. I've done my research and found solutions, but I can't fake it.
More specification ,my goal is to protect the two transmission lines A and B against bad connections (sometimes technicians plug in one of the lines a 24v or 48v DC voltage)

Comment: Can you ask a question please?

Comment: Welcome.  You'll find you get the best from EE.SE if you give quite a lot of details (a circuit diagram, part number, link to datasheets) so the people have a lot of information to help you in a precise way.

Comment: is there a solution to protect rs485 against continuous overvoltages for example 24V, 32V,... ETC.
I thought of using TVS SM712, but I can't do a virtual simulation. So during my research, I found analog device published an article (a solution based on TVS, GDT and TBU to protect RS485). Link: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/safeguard-your-rs-485-communication-networks.html
Is this solution applicable for my PCB circuit?

Comment: Circuits to protect against ESD won’t necessarily work with constant over-voltage. I used a SA5.0 transzorb and 100mA polyfuse to protect against 24VDC. The transzorb has to be sized to cope with the trip current of the polyfuse and the 5V drop across it.

Comment: my goal is to protect the two transmission lines A and B against bad connections (sometimes technicians plug in one of the lines a 24v or 48v DC voltage)

Comment: So, overvoltage or cross-wiring protection? Consider using interfaces tolerant of it, e.g. https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/lt1785-lt1791-60v-fault-tolerant-rs485-rs422-transceivers.html

Comment: Sir, the problem is the following, my PCB Contains several different headers to connect qlq for sensors, power supply, rs485. Technicians quite a few times they connect the power supply to the RS485 header terminal in pins A and B, I I tried to protect my rs485 against continuous overvoltage (for example 24V OR 48v..etc)

Comment: This is super common problem in industrial setting. Either use RS485 transceiver with common mode range >36V or place a protection circuitry, similar to what @Kartman described.

Comment: Is the solution mentioned by ANALOG DEVICE (TVS, TBU, GDT) not a sufficient solution in my case. Does he test Mr kartman solution, he will have a good result or how.@ 
Andrejs Gasilovs

Comment: In my mind, you better of simply selecting an RS485 transceiver with the required bus protection.
Go, for instance, to https://www.ti.com/interface/rs-485-rs-422/products.html and use a filter "Fault protection (V)" according to your needs.
For example, THVD2410 can tolerate ±70-V fault on A and B lines as differential or
common-mode with respect to GND

Comment: Thank you very much, I have already thought about this solution but these types of transceivers are very expensive.